# How should I get a user to indicate a file path to a directory in a command line program?

Tags: python-2.7, argparse

I am developing a command line program that requires the user to indicate a number of arguments for the Namespace object, and I am right now I am unsure how to design an argument that would allow the user to indicate the file path to a directory that would contain some text files required by the program to run.

Because I am trying to make this command line program portable (i.e. it can work on Linux, Mac, and Windows), I am not sure how I should design the argument to allow users from different platforms to indicate their pertinent file path, since a file path in Windows must utilize back slashes, as opposed to file paths in Mac or Linux.

How should I go about designing the argument as set up below?

```
import argparse
from os import path

Parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog= "Parser")
Parser.description= "This program helps with stuff blah blah blah"

Parser.add_argument("-input_dir", help= "Please indicate the file path that points to the location of the input text files.")

Parser.add_argument("-input_text", help= "Please indicate the specific text file you want to analyze.")

args= Parser.parse_args()

file_path= args.input_dir
text_file= path.join(file_path, args.input_text)
```

**ADDENDUM**

I should note that, what I am trying to accomplish is allow the user to type their file path into the command line with the other arguments, so that their input would look something like:

```
python testcript.py -input_dir ~/Documents/Input_Directory -input_text somefile.txt
```

and would still work on multiple platforms.

Comment: You can use single forward slashes on windows as well

Comment: Look at `sys.argv` to see how the shell has translated your commandline into a list of strings.  That's what `argparse` has to work with.  Sometimes the commandline needs escape characters or quotes to bypass its own parsing.

Comment: As written your code will work on multiple platforms.  Are you asking how to expand (for example) `~` into `/home/user` on UNIX or `C:\\User` on Windows?

Comment: @hpaulj could you explain how `sys.argv` and the list of strings entered into the command line are connected? When I type it into my IDE prompt, it gives me `['-c',' -f','/var/folders/03/32bw0xmn3c59_9wn5tyrm2t00000gn/T/tmpshomvv.json', '--pylab=qt']`, which doesn't seem to correlate with my command line program at all.

Comment: @SethMMorton that is more or less what I am asking, yes. At this point, a user could type in for the input directory argument `-input_dir /home/user/Documents/input_dir` and it would only work on a UNIX machine. How should I structure the argument so that users can type in file paths from Windows or Unix? Alternatively, because of UNIX dockers that work in both UNIX and Windows machines, this whole question might be moot. But I don't know how to use dockers, so I am trying to see what can be one to allow portability in this particular case.

Comment: @BobMcBobson Here is my confusion over what you are asking. `/home/user/Documents/input_dir` won't exist on a Windows machine, so a user wouldn't type that in on a Windows machine and seriously expect anything useful to happen. But nonetheless `os.path` will know how to handle your paths for either system no matter which system you are currently on. I think you need to articulate *much* more clearly what is your definition of providing `-input_dir /home/user/Documents/input_dir` and having it "work on a Windows machine" (you can start by giving your definition of work).

Comment: @SethMMorton Maybe I'm over-analyzing this whole problem since I don't have access to a Windows machine at this moment, but what I want is that my command line program knows in which folder to search for the user-specified input file. Maybe it would be less complicated if the user had to supply the entire file path including their input file, but I thought (for some reason) that portability would be better if the file path and input file were supplied separately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are *seriously* over-thinking this. It sounds that at the heart of the question is a lack of confidence that `os.path` *actually* works cross-platform. Let me assure you, it does! This module has been around for 27 years(!), working on both Windows and UNIX without issue.

Rather than assuming something won't work and then preemptively searching for a workaround (that possibly involves reinventing the wheel), you should instead test it out and see if it works or not. In the future this will save a lot of heartburn worrying about non-issues.

In one of the comments you expressed concern about being able to separate the filename from the directory in a cross-platform way, which is why you want the user to give them independently. This is incorrect thinking. The sane way to approach this would be to just get the full path from the user and break it yourself (users hate doing extra work if not necessary).

```
import argparse
import os.path

Parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog= "Parser")
Parser.description= "This program helps with stuff blah blah blah"

# Added required=True since I imagine you need this path...
Parser.add_argument("-text-file", help= "Please indicate the path to the text file.", required=True)

args= Parser.parse_args()

def make_path_sane(p):
    """Function to uniformly return a real, absolute filesystem path."""
    # ~/directory -> /home/user/directory
    p = os.path.expanduser(p)
    # A/.//B -> A/B
    p = os.path.normpath(p)
    # Resolve symbolic links
    p = os.path.realpath(p)
    # Ensure path is absolute
    p = os.path.abspath(p)
    return p

text_file = make_path_sane(args.text_file)
input_dir = os.path.dirname(text_file)
input_text = os.path.basename(text_file)
print text_file
print input_dir
print input_text
```

With this setup, the user can *choose* to give a full path, relative path, or just the file name itself *and it will always work!* On any file system!

```
% python2 parse.py -text-file ~/directory/file.txt
/home/smmorton/directory/file.txt
/home/smmorton/directory
file.txt

% python2 parse.py -text-file /home/smmorton/directory/file.txt
/home/smmorton/directory/file.txt
/home/smmorton/directory
file.txt

% python2 parse.py -text-file directory/file.txt
/home/smmorton/directory/file.txt
/home/smmorton/directory
file.txt

% cd ~/directory
% python2 parse.py -text-file file.txt
/home/smmorton/directory/file.txt
/home/smmorton/directory
file.txt

% python2 parse.py -text-file ../directory/./file.txt
/home/smmorton/directory/file.txt
/home/smmorton/directory
file.txt
```

---

If you were using Python >= 3.4, I would recommend you use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) instead of `os.path`.

Comment: Yeah, I was definitely overthinking this.... I've been trying to redo this project for its portability and have been so locked in on restructuring a lot of the functions that I got locked in the little details. But out of curiosity, could you tell me why you have the four different `os.path` methods inside your `make_sane_path` function? Wouldn't one be enough, for the sake of determining the file path?

Comment: I think that you should study the [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) documentation.  I have added comments to the function to make it clear what each does, but this goes back to the statement in my answer that you should test things out before making assumptions.  Eliminate all but one of the functions from `make_sane_path` and run the program with each of the path formats that I gave in the examples, and the you can figure out for yourself what each does and why I used all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.path.join(input_dir, "file1.txt")` and it will handle all OS specific issues. You have correctly initialized the parser, use the input directory and the `os.path.join` also `os.path.exists` to open your input files.

Quoting the reference: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html

> Since different operating systems have different path name conventions, there are several versions of this module in the standard library. The os.path module is always the path module suitable for the operating system Python is running on, and therefore usable for local paths. However, you can also import and use the individual modules if you want to manipulate a path that is always in one of the different formats.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I know that you can circumvent platform-dependent file path syntax by using `os.path`, but my question should have been stated, how can I set up the command line so someone can write into the command line `-input_dir ~/Documents/InputDirectory`. I'll go back to edit my question better

Comment: Why do you think that your code wont work on different platforms?\

Comment: I'm not sure.... I just assumed it would be a problem, but it is conceivable that I'm just over-analyzing the problem right now, and that if I use `path.join` the code will work fine. I will try to find a Windows machine and I will let you know what happens.